# Setting Up a Private Class in Java

Tags: java, class, private

New user here.

I've been working on a "framework" or draft for a text based adventure game in my object oriented programming class. I showed it to my TA and he said it looked good, but I should try putting the movement in its own private class. Any reason why I should do this? And how I should do it?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Here is my code for my main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    // This is where we will build rooms

    // Load inventory
    ArrayList<String> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

    // Start game
    boolean playing = true;

    while (playing) {

        String input = Input.getInput();

        // Movement commands
        if (input.equals("north")) {
            if (y > 0) {
                y--;
                Rooms.print(room, x, y);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You can't go that way.");
            }
        } else if (input.equals("south")) {
            if (y < HEIGHT - 1) {
                y++;
                Rooms.print(room, x, y);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You can't go that way.");
            }
        } else if (input.equals("east")) {
            if (x > 0) {
                x--;
                Rooms.print(room, x, y);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You can't go that way.");
            }
        } else if (input.equals("west")) {
            if (x < WIDTH - 1) {
                x++;
                Rooms.print(room, x, y);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You can't go that way.");
            }
        }

        // Look commands
        else if (input.equals("look")) {
            Rooms.print(room, x, y);
        }

        // Look at item commands
        else if (input.equals("look thing")) {
            //print item description
        }

        /* Take command
        else if statement

        Drop command
        else if statement

        */

        // Inventory commands
        else if (input.equals("i") || input.equals("inv")
                || input.equals("inventory")) {
            Inventory.print(inventory);
        }

        // Quit commands
        else if (input.equals("quit")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            playing = false;

        // Catch-all for invalid input
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good job on your first post. One tip I can give you is to refactor all of your `System.out.println("You can't go that way.");` into a function and call it. You are repeating this one line a few times and you may want to change it later, easier to do in 1 function, instead of finding every occurrence of that string.

Comment: You could use a `switch` on `input` for all of your commands. It is a bit clearer.

Comment: You should yank all your logic and put in a different class. Then make an instance of that class in main method and run the program. This way your logic and your  main class will be separate. I believe that is what your TA meant. Not sure about the 'private' part though.

Comment: Here's a way you can clean it up a bit. Instead of all the if-else-if blocks you can use a [Switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses. I will look more into using switch statements and also put all the logic in one whole class. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason that you would want to put the movement in its' own class is to enable what is known as [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Following this principle, you want to keep your classes as distinct and unique as possible.

This approach makes debugging/developing much easier as your program grows in size and complexity.

As far as making the class private, I don't know that I necessarily agree with that. I would simply make a `movement` class that handles all the movement related functions and data. Put this in its' own file that is separate from your main file, but within your project.

You can follow the same approach for your game inventory, attacking (if this exists), settings, etc.!

*As my comment mentions:*
One tip I can give you is to refactor all of your `System.out.println("You can't go that way.");` into a function and call it. You are repeating this one line a few times and you may want to change it later, easier to do in 1 function, instead of finding every occurrence of that string.

```
public static void moveError() {
     System.out.println("You can't go that way.");
}
```

A few people in the comments have reccommended transitioning into a switch statement. I agree with this approach; it's not only easier to look at. But easier to maintain as well. You can use specific 'commands' passed as strings/integers/characters that represent specific functions within your code:

```
switch (direction) {
   case "up":
      // code to move up and error handle
      break;
   case "down":
      // code to move down and error handle
      break;
}
```

You can also implement specific commands for things like picking up items, adjusting settings, or whatever else you envision.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Room Movement functionality that your TA is asking you to enclose within a private class is completely related to your outer class and hence has no significance if existed independently.